# Check AngularJS version from the console

Tags: angularjs

Is there a command to test AngularJS version from browser console like the `$().jquery` command for jQuery which returns the version of jQuery used in the page?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`angular.version` is what you're looking for: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/object/angular.version

Comment: If only you want to check the version then go to console and enter angular.version.full